# jQuery TagCloud

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Hi I am trying to write a tag cloud using jquery xml+MySql and php. I am trying to build a list of HREF's using jQuery and then populate a div with them. They are styled differently depending on the amount of times they are found in the db (COUNT(GenreName) as Count). The div isn't being populated with the list. I am wondering if it is a problem with the way I have created the list... or an I wayyyy off in my methodology.
What I have done so far is this

```
function GetGenres (){
var Count = array();
var GenreName=array();
var tagcloudLink

$.post("tagcloud.php", function(data){

    //create list for Genre tags
    $("<ul>").attr("id", "tagList").appendTo("#tagCloud");

    //create list item
    var li = $("<li>");

    $('row', data).each(function(i){

       Genre[i] = $(this).find("GenreName").text();
       Count[i] = $(this).find("Count").text();

        tagCloudLink += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"Genre_Clicked('"+Genre[i]+"')\">'"+ Genre[i] + "'</a>"; 

        tagCloudLink.appendTo(li);

        //set tag size
        li.children().css("fontSize", (Count[i] / 10 < 1) ? Count[i] / 10 + 1 + "em": (Count[i] / 10 > 2) ? "2em" : val.freq / 10 + "em");

        //add to list
        li.appendTo("#tagList");
    });
}, 'xml');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
      GetGenres();
});
```

Also Here is a sample of the XML

`<result>
−
<row>
<Count>5</Count>
<GenreName>Action</GenreName>
</row></result>`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tagList isn't being populated with the list of Genre Hrefs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code as follows:

```
function GetGenres(){   
    $.post('tagcloud.php', function(data){
        //create list for Genre tags
        var $ul = $('<ul>').attr('id', 'tagList');

        var Count = [];
        var GenreName = [];

        $(data).find('row').each(function(i){
            GenreName[i] = $(this).find('GenreName').text();
            Count[i] = $(this).find('Count').text();

            var $li = $('<li>');

            if( (Count[i] / 10) < 1 ) {
                var fontSize = (Count[i] / 10 + 1) + 'em';
            } else if( (Count[i] / 10) > 2 ) {
                var fontSize = '2em';
            } else {
                var fontSize = (Count[i] / 10) + 'em';
            }

            var $tagCloudLink = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)">')
                .text(GenreName[i])
                .css('font-size', fontSize)
                .bind('click', function(){
                    Genre_Clicked( GenreName[i] )
                });

            // add to list item
            $tagCloudLink.appendTo($li);

            // add to main list
            $li.appendTo($ul);
        });

        // add to container div
        $ul.appendTo('#tagCloud');
    }, 'xml');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    GetGenres();
});
```

**Question:**

- <strike>Where is `val.freq` coming from? I've included it above, but obviously it won't work as is.</strike> OP noted that `val.freq` should be `Count[i]`.

**Some pointers:**

- When making changes to the DOM, you want to limit the number of times you write to it. So it's generally preferable to create all your dynamic elements in memory, then write to the DOM in one shot.
- If you plan on using `Genre[]` or `Count[]` after the initial data processing, they'll only be available within the scope of `$.post()` due to the asynchronous call. I would suggest passing them to another function or using them inside `$.post()`.

**EDIT:**

- Guess it would help if I changed `Genre[i]` to `GenreName[i]`.
- I've tested the main data processing loop above by ripping it out and replacing `data` with a simple array of the form `[ [genre0,count0], ... ]`. It works as expected so hopefully you can adapt it further if this still doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the refactoring. Its nice to see well structured code after looking at my messy incarnation for the past 3 month. val.freq should have been Count[], I have changed that. It still doesn't populate the div, but I have a feeling that this problem may lie elsewhere. Its been a long day of code so I think I will look at it with fresh eyes in the morning. Thanks for looking at it for me. I will take into account your pointers too, thanks again.

Comment: Hi again. I still haven't managed to get it to work. At count1 it is still in the loop and displays '0' during the first iteration. At Count2 it has bottomed out.  The problem may lie at `bind('click', Genre_Clicked( GenreName[i] )`. At this point the alert box I have within the Genre_Clicked function is called.   `alert("count1" + i);
            var $tagCloudLink = $('<a href="javascript:void(0)">')
                .text(GenreName[i])
                .css('font-size', fontSize)
                .bind('click', Genre_Clicked( GenreName[i] ));
   alert("count2" + i);`

Comment: @RonanC: Try `.bind('click', function(){Genre_Clicked(GenreName[i]);});`

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetGenres (){
var Count = [];
var GenreName=[];
var tagcloudLink;
var loopCounter = 0;

$.post("tagcloud.php", function(data){

    //create list for Genre tags
    $("<ul>").attr("id", "tagList").appendTo("#tagCloud");




$(data).find('row').each(function() {

                Genre[loopCounter] = $(this).find('Count').text();
            Count[loopCounter] = $(this).find('GenreName').text();
            tagCloudLink += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\"onclick=\"Genre_Clicked('"+Genre[loopCounter]+"')\">'"+ Genre[loopCounter] + "'</a>"; 

                    //create list item
            var li = $("<li/>");

            tagCloudLink.appendTo(li); 

            li.children().css("fontSize",loopCounter ); 

            li.appendTo("#tagList");

                    loopCounter += 1;

                },'xml');



});


$(document).ready(function() {
      GetGenres();
});
```

its untested but you'll get the idea

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am getting an error using this code using firebug. "second argument to Function.prototype.apply must be an array" Any Ideas?